# Eliminar imágenes en carpeta en android

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo podría vaciar una carpeta desde java?

Estoy en un proyecto en Android Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Para eliminar los archivos dentro de un folder, esta es una forma:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"nombre_folder"); 
//comprueba si es directorio.
if (dir.isDirectory()) 
{
     //obtiene un listado de los archivos contenidos en el directorio.
    String[] hijos = dir.list();
     //Elimina los archivos contenidos.
    for (int i = 0; i < hijos.length; i++)
    {
       new File(dir, hijos[i]).delete();
    }
}
```

En el caso que desees eliminar recursivamente directorios ya que podria contener tu directorio más directorios dentro, puedes usar este método:

```
void borraRecursivamente(File archivoODirectorio) {
    if (archivoODirectorio.isDirectory())
        for (File hijos : archivoODirectorio.listFiles())
            borraRecursivamente(hijos);

    archivoODirectorio.delete();
}
```

Tomado de la [respuesta de @teedyay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425744/250260)

Comment: Quizá no está  tomando en cuenta si dentro del directorio hay subdirectorios? O me equivoco. Quizá.

Comment: El OP no especifica eso en su pregunta. Pero agregaré más datos a mi respuesta.

Comment: Indirectamente cuando dice vaciar si lo da a entender :). Saludos

Comment: Ok gracias por la observación.

Comment: ??? A que te refieres??? No entiendo porque tengo -1.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes Eliminar archivos de todo tipo  de Forma `Recursiva` de un directorio con esta función. (Ojalá te ayude) ,

```
void EliminarArchivos(File ArchivoDirectorio) { /* Parametro File (Ruta) */
  if (ArchivoDirectorio.isDirectory()) /* Si es Directorio */
   {
      /* Recorremos sus Hijos y los ELiminamos */
      for (File hijo : ArchivoDirectorio.listFiles()) 
           EliminarArchivos(hijo); /*Recursividad Para Saber si no hay Subcarpetas */
   }
  else 
      ArchivoDirectorio.delete(); /* Si no, se trata de un File ,solo lo Eliminamos*/
}
```

Para acceder a la Función Sería así

```
EliminarArchivos(new File("ruta") );
```

Comment: disculpa en donde iria la ruta del directorio lo quisiera poner en /storage/emulated/0/mi_carpeta/

Comment: Cuando llames a la Función , modifiqué mi respuesta . donde está ruta ahí va la ruta a Eliminar :)